# what's the difference between src/**/* and 'src/**/*'

Tags: node.js, typescript, nodemon

I want to start my project with `nodemon`

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "tsc && node build/index.js",
  "watch-server1": "nodemon --watch src/**/* -e ts,tsx --exec ts-node ./src/index.ts",
  "watch-server2": "nodemon --watch 'src/**/*' -e ts,tsx --exec 'ts-node' ./src/index.ts"
},
```

But when I use `watch-server1`:

```
(node:6830) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
/Users/leonsux/Desktop/Code/home/src/router/index.js:5
export default router;
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1167:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1215:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1272:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1100:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:962:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at main (/Users/leonsux/Desktop/Code/home/node_modules/ts-node/src/bin.ts:198:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/leonsux/Desktop/Code/home/node_modules/ts-node/src/bin.ts:288:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1251:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1272:10)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

When I use `watch-server2`, it works well

So, what's the difference between `src/**/*` and `'src/**/*'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unquoted shell characters like `*` will be expanded by your shell (e.g. bash) before the arguments are passed to `nodemon`.

Quoting them in single quotes will protect them from being expanded by the shell, so `nodemon` will be passed the literal string `src/**/*` as an argument. (Which it can do what it likes with—presumably expanding the wildcard itself.)

An example of where this makes a big difference:

```
scp 'remoteserver:*.txt' .
```

Versus:

```
scp remoteserver:*.txt .
```

Quoting the `*` allows scp to open a secure connection to the remote server and see what files exist on it.

If `*` got expanded by your local shell, it would just look for files with names like "remoteserver:foo.txt" on your local machine and presumably find none.

Comment: +1. Note that in many shells, fileglobs are left alone if no matches are found; so something like `scp remoteserver:*.txt .` is likely to work . . . right up until it doesn't. (That's the behavior specified by POSIX, and it's the behavior of Bash with default settings.)

Comment: @ruakh I wasn't aware of that. I mostly use tcsh, which just says "command: no match" if a fileglob can't be expanded.